# Difference between `--privileged` and `--cap-add=all` in docker

Tags: linux, docker, containers, cgroups, linux-capabilities

Background: I am running a docker container which needs to load/remove a kernel module which makes USB devices attached to a remote server available on the host which I then want to make available in the container.

It works when running the container with `—-privileged` and bind mounts for `/lib/modules` and `/dev`.

Now I want to remove privileged mode and just allow the minimum necessary access. I tried `—-cap-add=all` as a start, but that doesn’t seem enough. What else does `—-privileged` allow?

Comment: this also answers the question `what is the difference between "--privileged" and "--security-opt seccomp=unconfined"?`: privlileged gives more. seccomp=unconfined only gives access to additional syscalls.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Setting privileged should modify:

- capabilities: removing any capability restrictions
- devices: the host devices will be visible
- seccomp: removing restrictions on allowed syscalls
- apparmor/selinux: policies aren't applied
- cgroups: I don't believe the container is limited within a cgroup

That's from memory, I might be able to find some more digging in the code if this doesn't point you too your issue.

p.s. here is a link to the documentation on what `--privileged` does: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#runtime-privilege-and-linux-capabilities

Comment: Fantastic, thank you! Any idea where I could find this documented? I had a look at the source, but all I could find was the lifting of capability restrictions here: https://github.com/moby/moby/blob/46cdcd206c56172b95ba5c77b827a722dab426c5/daemon/exec_linux.go

Comment: @nfelger not sure. If it's not documented somewhere, it really should be. This was just from memory.

Comment: @nfelger there's a variety of settings configured when you create the container: https://github.com/moby/moby/blob/470ae8422fc6f1845288eb7572253b08f1e6edf8/daemon/oci_linux.go