# Difference between privileged and capabilities

Tags: docker, kubernetes, privileges, linux-capabilities

I am trying to authorize a Kubernetes pod with Capability in securityContext.

*[Set capabilities for a Container](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/security-context/#set-capabilities-for-a-container)*

I followed this document to check */proc/1/status* and find some information about pods.
But I found that "inside pod, it seems that logically I authorized SYS_ADMIN and status seems to be perfect. But it doesn't work. So I tried giving privileged mode and dropped "ALL" capabilities, but it still doesn’t work (all capabilities are available inside a privileged pod.

I've checked

1. Give *All Capabilities Without privilege*
2. Privileged Pod
3. Privileged Pod Dropping all Capability

but all the proc/status says is

```
CapInh: 0000003fffffffff
CapPrm: 0000000000000000
CapEff: 0000000000000000
CapBnd: 0000003fffffffff
CapAmb: 0000000000000000
```

But case 1 doesn't have any permission to mount or see several files inside */dev*.

And case 3 has all the permission to mount or see all the files inside */dev* (such as *tty5*).

I checked all the status on Kubernetes, but it was still the same on Docker.

Personally, I can only think, all the capabilities won’t work (including add and drop), so I want to know what the difference is.

---

#### Case 1

```
    securityContext:
      capabilities:
        add:
        - ALL
```

#### Case 2

```
    securityContext:
      privileged: true
```

#### Case 3

```
    securityContext:
      privileged: true
      capabilities:
        drop:
        - ALL
```

Comment: Do you have a higher-level goal for this, particularly in Kubernetes?  Remember that a typical production Kubernetes application runs multiple replicas spread across multiple nodes, and that there will be multiple pods running on each node, so a privileged container (if you're allowed to run one at all) will only be able to manage its own node, and different replicas will see different things.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between \`--privileged\` and \`--cap-add=all\` in docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66635237/difference-between-privileged-and-cap-add-all-in-docker)

Comment: @TrevorBoydSmith only in capabilites they are same. but they have other problems. thanks for you answer

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. It wasn't problem inside kubernetes but node's security option. I tested same capabilities option in docker and found that "app-armor" was the problem.

in docker option

```
--security-opt apparmor:unconfined
```

will allow me to have permission to get capabilites.